# How can I create a clustered column chart as a drilldown in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts

I am looking to build a column chart that has a drilldown into a grouped column chart.

The following fiddle shows the rough plan of what I'm intending, except it is producing the same series regardless of which drilldown I click on.

https://jsfiddle.net/h5xm9dov/

I'm very novice at JS, but the plan is to use this structure as a base to then pass data onto it in R using the `highcharter` package.

This is my current attempt in R:

```
main_series_data <- tibble(
  id = c("Animals"),
  name= c("Animals"),
  y = c(10),
  drilldown = c("Animals")
)

# Drilldown series data
drilldown_series <- list(
  list(
    id = "Animals",
    name = "Animals",
    data = list(
      list("Cows", 2),
      list("Sheep", 3)
    )
  ),
  list(
    id = "Animals",
    name = "Animals2",
    data = list(
      list("Cows", 22),
      list("Sheep", 13)
    )
  )
)

hchart(
  main_series_data,
  "column",
  hcaes(x = name, y = y, drilldown = drilldown))%>% 
  hc_drilldown(
    series = drilldown_series
  )
```

However, this only plots the 2nd list in the `drilldown_series`.

Answer (score -1):

Below is a simplified R code of a configuration that matches the description of what you're trying to achieve: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1wbsjemo/

I hope this will make your work easier!

```
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)

main_data <- data_frame(
  name = c("Animals", "Fruits", "Cars"),
  y = c(5, 2, 4),
  drilldown = c("animals", "fruits", "cars")
)

drilldown_series <- list(
  list(
    id = "animals",
    data = list(
      list("Cats", 4),
      list("Dogs", 2),
      list("Cows", 1),
      list("Sheep", 2),
      list("Pigs", 1)
    )
  ),
  list(
    id = "fruits",
    data = list(
      list("Apples", 4),
      list("Oranges", 2)
    )
  ),
  list(
    id = "cars",
    data = list(
      list("Toyota", 4),
      list("Opel", 2),
      list("Volkswagen", 2)
    )
  )
)

highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = "column") %>%
  hc_title(text = "Basic drilldown") %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "category") %>%
  hc_legend(enabled = FALSE) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(series = list(
    borderWidth = 0,
    dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE)
  )) %>%
  hc_add_series(
    name = "Things",
    colorByPoint = TRUE,
    data = main_data,
    drilldown = TRUE
  ) %>%
  hc_drilldown(series = drilldown_series)
```

Comment: I need the drill down to be clustered though, like how in my example there is two sets of animal data.